# Use socket-io controller on several files

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

im new to angularJS and socket-io (client side webpage) and i am strugling to keep the code organized.

I created the controller for socket connections (for server side), however i want to use the controller on several partials.

I've read that services should be used for that (independent of views) but all services that i search are using controllers on it.
Can anyone help me?

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';
var appSocketController = angular.module('appSocketController', [btford.socket-io'])

.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
  var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:3701');
  var mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
  });  
  return mySocket;
});

appSocketController.controller('SocketCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {
  socket.on('connect', function() { {logic code...} }
  $scope.updateData = function(data) { $scope.data = data; }
});
```

I want to be able to recieve/send msgs and update the views accourdingly to this controller, however i would like to be able to split each view/partial controller for other logic

I am using this routing config:

```
ALIASWebApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl' // + SocketCtrl?
  }).
  when('/lights', { ///:lightId
    templateUrl: 'partials/lights.html',
    controller: 'LightsCtrl' // + SocketCtrl?
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
}]);
```